# neo4j-admin import not ignoring field delimiter within " "

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to import a series of csv's into neo4j using the neo4j-admin import tool. Some of the records I'm importing contain the field delimiter character (Whatever character I choose as the field delimiter, it seems at least one record contains it). Supposedly, this shouldn't be a problem, since the fields are surrounded by " " (https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/properly-escaping-input-data-for-neo4j-import/). However, the import process fails and produces an error.

Here's an example record:

```
|"Keller, Bess|Sack, Joetta L."|author
```

My delimiter is set to be  "|" and my record contains "|".

Here is the error I get from the import tool:

```
Error in input data
Caused by:Extra column not present in header on line 1170 in ....
```

If surrounding the record in " " does not prevent the import tool from recognizing the delimiter, how can I escape the delimiter character within the field?

Neo4j CE 3.3.0

RHEL 6.9

Comment: I know this does not answer the question, but does escaping the character resolve the problem? That is, `|"Keller, Bess\|Sack, Joetta L."|author` should work.

Comment: Yes, I did try that but didn't work, it just gave me the same error.

Comment: How do you set the delimiter? I created a small example file and got it working with the legacy `neo4j-import` tool: `./neo4j-import --nodes:Hello file.csv --into /tmp/hello --delimiter "` I do not see an option to set the delimiter in the `neo4j-admin import tool though.

Comment: It looks like version 3.3 of `neo4j-admin import` [added support for additional arguments to match `neo4j-import`](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/9360).

Comment: Could I use '||' as my delimiter instead?